# Interceptor in PHP

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I want to intercept a request to a PHP page, then read the data from url(key:value format) and then forward the request to the PHP page.

Can somebody suggest an approach to do this task? I am using apache 2.4 as webserver and php 5.6.24.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Would I be right in saying what you're trying to achieve is to intercept a state change in a specific action/function?

Comment: If I put in simple words, I send a request to a php script and I just want to print the data in url and then transfer the request to php script.

Answer (score 0):

I used "require" in start of the php file and then in that file a performed some activity on the url and redirected to the intended page.